# MySql wont connect to datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I got a problem with my WPF datagrid. I simply can't get it to connect with my MySql database. I have tried alot of things, and changed my code a hundred of times. I get the error that it cant connect with MySql and so on.

All help is appreciated :)

```
namespace Uniscrap_DocumentPacker
{

    public partial class Uniscrap : Window
    {

        public Uniscrap()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                MainWindow MainWin = new MainWindow();

                MainWin.Show();
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnFill_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                try
                {
                    string connectionString = "Server=server.ip ;Database=dbName;User Id=User Id;Password=pass";
                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Importer", con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }
            }
        }
        public System.Windows.ResizeMode ResizeMode { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Comment: what type of authentication is set up on your sql server? Do you have any firewalls that might be blocking your connection on port 1433?

Comment: Its Sql server authentication, where do i check with the firewalls.?

Comment: Remove that `catch{}` and check for errors. At the very least *log* the error. There's probably an exception complaining about the invalid `User ID` keyword which gets hidden by `catch{}`

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are two completely different database products.

Comment: I used your code to connect to my MySQL and it connects fine without errors.. I can read the data as well. Check your firewall or port access to your mySQL 3306 (unless its something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL connection string and method is valid and I am able to use that to connect to the my MySQL server and retrieve the data, without making any changes (well, besides DB name and such).

Please check

1. your Server IP is valid
2. you are using Correct DB name ... (not table)
3. you have access to connect to the MySQL server on port it is using (default 3306) (You can use powershell to check port access: Test-NetConnection -ComputerName server -Port 3306
4. Use Workbench or any other MySQL UI to connect from the system you have the code deployed to see if you can connect to DB.

I would have posted code that works, but yours already do !!

Comment: @ThobiasFiskerMunkstrup see changed recommendations

Comment: what was the issue and how did you solve it? could you share that with us :)

Comment: The problem was some Syntax mistakes. First of, I wasn't aware of that MySql and Sql Server wasnt the same. Big newbie mistake. And then i had a problem with port that wast easily fixed :)